# objc - how to scroll a tableview to a cell based on time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

There are lots of questions on tapping a cell. This question is about showing cells. I have a tableview with cells for a day, by hour.

I want the tableview to scroll to "now". Is this possible?

I can change the color of a cell this way:
 (in `cellforRowAtIndexPath`)

First construct two unix times - one for now, and another for the incoming time.. Then, simply

```
if (time == 1) { //future

        time = 0;
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        cell.detailLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    } else { //past
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.detailLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];


    }
```

I'm looking at :

`[scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:scrollPosition animated:]` but I'm not sure I'm on the right track, nor how to use this method. Thanks for any help.

Comment: That is the method you need to use, but you need to identify the indexPath of the cell that you want to scroll to - presumably you can just take the current hour using NSDateComponents

Comment: Thanks for that.  I know how to make the date component, but how do I use the method? I would presumably have to iterate over the table until I can identify a specific time. I don't  know how to link the iterations to the scroll method. If you could dive me an example on how to use this method, that might open my eyes..

Comment: How is your data model mapped to your table?  Do you simply have an array of 24 hours or are there an arbitrary number of objects in your array, each with their own date field?

Comment: The latter.. Think of a schedule. There's a flight at 7 and another at nine and another at 10:30..

Comment: So you will need to iterate through your array to identify the first index where the hour matches the target hour.  This will be your `indexPath.row`

Comment: ok, then how do I fold that into this method? (Thanks for helping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your exact data model, but assuming there are an array of objects, each with an `NSDate` property you would use something like

```
-(void) scrollToHour:(NSInteger)targetHour {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    for (int i=0;i<self.dataObjects.count;i++) {
        MyObject *myObject=self.dataObjects[i];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:myObject.date];
        NSInteger hour = [components hour];
        if (hour >= targetHour) {
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works fine, except one more question... from where should I call the method? `cellForRowAtIndexPath` cannot be correct as then I cannot scroll normally.

Comment: When do you want the scroll to occur?  When the view is first displayed - `viewWillAppear` might be a good choice. After data has finished loading from some source - call it when the data is loaded. When the user taps a "now" button - in the button action handler